# Github API/Ruby/Octokit: Why does Octokit report 5056 total count but querying by GET request returns 1223281?

Tags: ruby, github-api, octokit

I've been playing about with Octokit to search for open issues.

I've used the following to search for open Ruby issues:

```
client.search_issues({ language: 'ruby', state: 'open' })
```

The response includes:

```
:total_count=>5056
```

However, when I query GH without using the Ruby wrapper:

```
res = open('https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=language:ruby+state:open')
JSON.parse res.read
```

The count is different:

```
"total_count"=>1223280
```

Why is this so? Why does one method result in a larger count than the other?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the url without any additional parameter, you are querying while being anonymous.

On the other side, if you have followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb#authentication) to authenticate yourself, the total count is over your own user limits.